# What can I do when I get a "Cannot Allocate Memory" error after restoring a disk image?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, osx-mountain-lion

I've downloaded Mac OS X Mountain Lion today and wanted to backup the installation image to a USB drive for later.

I've created a new empty partition of at least 8 GB size on the external drive using *Disk Utility*, and tried to restore the *InstallESD.dmg* image to this new partition, via the *Restore* menu.

However, doing that, I get the following error message, right after it finishes copying:

> Cannot Allocate Memory

What can I do now?

Comment: If you found this because you are trying to build a USB installer for Yosemite (or later), check out Christian Bongiorno's answer.

Comment: @slhck - can I get the check for the answer?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno You may notice that I provided an answer of my own which solved the issue for me at the time of writing (when I was using Lion / Mountain Lion).

Answer (score 11):

This works:

```
 /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/YOSEMITE/ --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app
```

Got it from [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) directly

Comment: Even though the original question came long before, now that Yosemite has pulled the rug out from under itself, a lot of people are going to run into this and will likely end up here, so thanks for sharing this answer!

Comment: ^ People like me. I think this is about the tenth time I've ended up here. Figured it was time to get my password off my phone and log in and up-vote it.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that there is a checksum mismatch for the disk image, or you experienced a bug in Disk Utility.

You can try to use the `asr` command-line utility to copy the image yourself. To do that, you need:

- The *InstallESD.dmg* image
- A large enough HFS+ partition on an external drive created through *Disk Utility*, let's call it `Install`
- A running terminal

In your terminal, enter the following line, but replace the path to your OS X installer image and the target partition:

> `asr restore --source Desktop/InstallESD.dmg --target /Volumes/Install`

Now, you should get output similar to the following:

```
Validating target...done
Validating source...done
Retrieving scan information...done
Validating sizes...done
Copying    ....10....20....30....40....50....60....70....80....90....asr: did not copy blessed information to target, which may have missing or out-of-date blessed folder information.
100
Ejecting the source image...done
```

Now, you can boot into the installer from your USB drive too. To verify if it worked, go to *System Preferences » Startup Disk*, and check if your installer appears:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `asr` command line suggested does not work under Mavericks, at least not in my case. (I get the error message `File copy is not supported anymore.  Use the --erase flag`).

I was able to get around the `Cannot allocate memory` error by simply mounting the .dmg and having it mounted when I do the restore.

Comment: Got the same: bash-3.2# asr restore --source  /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg --target /Volumes/YOSEMITE/
File copy is not supported anymore.  Use the --erase flag.
bash-3.2# asr restore --erase --source  /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg --target /Volumes/YOSEMITE/
        Validating target...done
        Validating source...done
Could not find any scan information. The source image needs to be imagescanned before it can be restored.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest for me has always been to use a dedicated external harddrive, and just format it as Mac OSX only. Sure its annoying not to be able to swop files with a PC but i think the drive you put your disk image on shouldn't be used for general storage, it should be stashed safely in a safe. Use another drive for copying files etc.